# react-native run-android build error - Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, gradle

I'm running react-native app via Android Studio and I keep running into a build error with the android support dependencies. I have the necessary SDK platform and tools installed via Android Studio and yet I still run into this error.

`Could not find com.android.support:support-v7:26.0.2.`

At first I was using 27.0.3, but then I noticed all of my libraries were defaulting to 26.0.2 as stated by the following warning message during the build -
`The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (26.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 will be used.`

I've consulted a variety of StackOverflow solutions and the build fails every time. Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong?

app/build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.jast"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
compile project(':react-native-aws')
compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
compile project(':react-native-mail')
compile project(':react-native-rate')
compile project(':appcenter-crashes')
compile project(':appcenter-analytics')
compile project(':appcenter')
compile project(':react-native-fcm')
compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
    transitive = false
}
compile project(':react-native-maps')
compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2"
compile "com.android.support:support-v7:26.0.2"
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following conditions in your code.

- Check to see if your there is `google()` in your project level build.gradle. If not make sure that where `jcenter()` occurs place `google()` above `jcenter()`.
- Check if `gradle-wrapper.properties` has the corresponding gradle version with regards to appcompat version and sdkversion in `defaultConfig` in app level build.gradle

Comment: - google() is above jcenter() in my project level build.gradle.

- As for gradle-wrapper.properties, what exactly should I be looking for to check for corresponding gradle versions ?

Answer (score 0):

update project level gradle dependencies to the latest version:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    }
```